# Angular 2 - routing inside a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular-routing

Yesterday I asked a question about an another specific thing of angular 2 routing and the answer was satisfying for me [Angular 2 — navigate through web pages without reloading a component that is common for those pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438164/angular-2-navigate-through-web-pages-without-reloading-a-component-that-is-com/40445890#40445890) . But when I got back to examining these things, I encountered a problem again. Here's the new version of the app: http://ivan-khludov.com/ . What if I want the pages of the private section to have a shared component (a counter in my example), don't reload it each time I navigate withing the section and at the same time display different components at different pages - the dashboard component at private/dashboard and the inbox component at private/inbox? Is it possible to do without reloading the counter and without storing the last value of the counter in memory? This is the entry point of the application and the root module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { ROUTES } from './routes';

import { AppWrapper } from './components/app-wrapper';

import { PublicSection } from './components/public';
import { PrivateSection } from './components/private';

import { Counter } from './components/counter';

import { Dashboard } from './components/private/dashboard';
import { Inbox } from './components/private/inbox';




@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppWrapper,
    PublicSection,
    PrivateSection,
    Counter,
    Dashboard,
    Inbox
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ 
    AppWrapper
  ]

})

class RootModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootModule);
```

Routing:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppWrapper } from '../components/app-wrapper';

import { PublicSection } from '../components/public';
import { PrivateSection } from '../components/private';




export const ROUTES: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/public/1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'section-1',
    redirectTo: '/public/1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'public/:page',
    component: PublicSection
  },
  {
    path: 'private',
    redirectTo: '/private/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'private/:page',
    component: PrivateSection
  }

];
```

The private section component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';




@Component({
  selector: 'private',
  template: `
  <h2>Private section — {{page}}</h2>
  <counter></counter>
  <dashboard></dashboard>
  <inbox></inbox>
  `
})

export class PrivateSection {

  private page: string;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(

    private route: ActivatedRoute

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.page = params['page'];
    });  

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

The dashboard component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';




@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  template: `
  <div>dashboard text: lorem ipsum</div>
  `
})

export class Dashboard {

}
```

The inbox component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';




@Component({
  selector: 'inbox',
  template: `
  <div>inbox text: dolor sit amet</div>
  `
})

export class Inbox {

}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can try Nested child routes. Refer this article - https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-routing

Comment: Thank you, it worked as a charm. I though that we can't use more than one router-outlet inside an application, so I hadn't tried that before your answer.

Comment: Please provide and accept an answer or close your question if it's resolved.